# What is preferred code/directory structure for extended modules?

Tags: phoenix-framework

What is equivalent of Rails `/lib` directory in Phoenix? and how code should be structured there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [What goes in Rails lib/](https://medium.com/extreme-programming/what-goes-in-rails-lib-92c74dfd955e):

> The generated Rails README proclaims:
>
> `lib` — Application specific libraries. Basically, any kind of custom
>   code that doesn’t belong under controllers, models, or helpers. This
>   directory is in the load path.
>
> The Rails guide says:
>
> `app/` Contains the controllers, models, views, helpers, mailers and
>   assets for your application.
>
> `lib/` Extended modules for your application.
>
> In other words, `app/` is
>   for “configuring Rails”, and `lib/` is code that would make sense even
>   if your application was ported to the console or an Android app for
>   instance.

The equivalent directory in phoenix would be: `your_app/lib/your_app`.

> and how code should be structured there?

All modules defined in a mix project's `/lib` directory are available in any other file in your project as `ModuleName.func_name()`. `Phoenix in Action` puts the public interface for your app in `your_app/lib/your_app.ex` with the rest of the files in the directory `your_app/lib/your_app/`.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be structured like any other Elixir application.

Quote taken from Phoenix Framework docs [Adding Page](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/adding_pages.html) section.

> Our lib/hello_web directory contains web-related files – routers, controllers, templates, channels, etc. The rest of our greater Elixir application lives inside lib/hello, and you structure code here like any other Elixir application.